# Real Characters and Legendre Symbols

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm studing an elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progression. In the middle of the proof, Selberg says that for every real Dirichlet Character mod $k$ there exists some integer $D$ such that $|D|< k^2$ and $\chi(p)=\left(\frac{D}{p}\right)$ for every $p$ prime, where $\left(\frac{D}{p}\right)$ is Legendre's Symbol.

How I could prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's $k{}{}$?

Comment: $k$ is the modulis of Dirichlet Character (I've edited)

Comment: What is the reference for this theorem?